# I need molecular dynamics simulations input file for hexagonal heterostructures in quantum espresso

Tags: molecular-dynamics, quantum-espresso, software-input-file-request, aimd, heterostructures

I m a material science student of PhD and search alot and make some input files for AIMD simulation but I didn't get the best output if anyone have the input file please provide me

Comment: [Here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/cp_user_guide/cp_user_guide.html) you will find an example input file with detailed explanation for ab initio molecular dynamics with the CP package of QE. You need to replace the `&SYSTEM`, `ATOMIC_SPECIES` and `ATOMIC_POSITIONS` part according to your hexagonal structure. Project 18.1 to 18.4 of [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGntAYRT8AVmQMyurFoncyOdHljqeGU_R) video tutorial shows various AIMD with QE.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin why not write that as an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani I think the OP needs to provide the information about his structure and some additional information such as the type of ensemble to use. Otherwise the question is too general to answer. That's why I referred to a general documentation instead of a specific answer.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin okay, if the OP needs to add more detail though, that needs to be made clear to the OP, especially since this OP is new. The first comment doesn't seem to ask OP for more details.

Comment: @UmairKhan if the comment solves your problem, let me know. I will add a general answer explaining the different parts of the input file. If it doesn't, let me know in that case too. Please provide some details such as what kind of hexagonal structure you are working on, what type of ensemble do you want (NVE/NVT) etc.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I made different input file with different tags especially using the car-parrinello but the cppp.x file making an issue didn't run and can't plot the graph. I used 2H phase hexagonal vdWHs for metal/semiconductor contact as TaX2-WXY. I need to calculate it's MD on quantum espresso that why I need a correct input file to plot the graph and get results. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NikeDattani I used 2H phase hexagonal vdWHs with ibrav=4 , consist of metal/semiconductor contact (TaX2-WXY) . I also tried my to make input file for MD simulation with the help of Car-parrinello given samples but at the end an issue occurs for cppp.x file running. So simply I need the MD input file. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the video

Comment: But Sir I want the input file if you provide me I will appreciate it @NikeDattani

Comment: @UmairKhan Please ask another question by uploading your cppp.x input file which was was creating the issues. Also mention what type of error message you were receiving or what issue you are talking about. Also state what graph you are achieving for. With these details included, ask another question please. This question is too vague to answer and the details you provided changed the question asked in the title.